# VB Form AxWindowMediaPlayer fullscreen when play

Tags: vb.net

How do I make the player go fullscreen when play ?

`

```
    If dirlabel.Text = "Not Selected" Then

        MsgBox(" Please select video first ")

    Else

        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = dirlabel.Text
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.autoStart = True
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.mute = True
        AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.uiMode = "full"

    End If

    AxWindowsMediaPlayer1.settings.setMode("Loop", True)



End Sub`
```

I try to find a way that can make the AxWindowMediaPlayer1 setting go full screen

Comment: Little hard to know without a bit more context.  What kind of app are you doing here?  Winforms?  What's the containing object for AxWindowsMediaPlayer1 and how are properties like size/location/anchoring/docking configured for AxWindowsMediaPlayer1 relative to what ever it's contained in?